# How do I push items or maybe add an element in array of array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, local-storage, push

Supposingly I have

```
0: {nick: "xaxa", pass: "215151", uid: "1123151", gallery: []}
1: {nick: "SamServer", pass: "mathlearner18", uid: "123456123456", gallery: []}
```

I want my item be push in the gallery that I can form it into something like this

```
gallery: [{img:"src",descrip:"text"},{img:"src",descrip:"text"},{img:"src",descrip:"text"},
{img:"src",descrip:"text"},{img:"src",descrip:"text"},{img:"src",descrip:"text"},]
```

I tried this by using push method `savedAccounts.gallery.push({img:"src",descript:"text"})` but it doesn't work. Can anyone of you guys tell me how it works? I have write this in a localStorage so I can make gallery storage for each accounts that I created. I"m actually passing the props of the `useState()` here so you guys can get my points

I have this `HeaderProfile.jsx` and then the format is like this

```
<HeaderProfile 
        item={Guest} 
        islogin = {islogin} 
        changeLog = {setislogin} 
        
        savedAcc = {savedAccounts}
        multisavedAcc = {setsavedAccounts}

        > </HeaderProfile>
```

wherein `const[savedAccounts,setsavedAccounts] = useState()` is my localStorage.
And I am passing this in a react hook component HeaderProfile.jsx **NOTE**

```
const [savedAccounts,setsavedAccounts] = 
0: {nick: "xaxa", pass: "215151", uid: "1123151", gallery: []}
1: {nick: "SamServer", pass: "mathlearner18", uid: "123456123456", gallery: []}
```

so I pass this in my `HeaderProfile.jsx` and here what it looks like

```
const handleUploadPost = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    multisavedAcc.gallery.push({img:gallery,description:textgallery})
    console.log(multisavedAcc.gallery.push({img:gallery,description:textgallery}))
}
```

I want to pass it to the Headerprofile.jsx and then push it to the gallery file for each target.

Edit I was thinking if it because I didn't make a right index where is my target for multisavedAcc[index] ? for the accounts owner

New issue Edited:

```
    const collectionGallery = savedAcc.map((el,i) => {
    let gallery_
    console.log(gallery_)
    if(el.uid == uid) {
        gallery_ = el.gallery.map((items,j) => {
            return(
                <div>
                    <div className='item-sample' key={j} onClick={e => togglePopupImageEdit(j)}>   
                        <div className="img-item">
                        <img src= {items.img} alt="" /> 
                        </div>
                        <h3> {items.description} </h3>
                        
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={e => handleDeleteItem(j)}> Delete </button>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }

    return(
        <div className="collection-photo">
            {gallery_}
        </div>
    )
})
```

As you can see I want to call back the items so that I can show it in return but when I tried to refresh it...the images are vanish but in the localStorage it is still there please help sir. I am almost done i just want my image don't vanish..

and here is the console error

```
   blob:http://localhost:3000/fb44255c-d443-4b54-8cbe-860338b6f2ed:1 
   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
     blob:http://localhost:3000/04d545aa-8ecb-4412-a59f-088cd01a793d:1 
   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
      blob:http://localhost:3000/3d5e6bff-cfbe-4182-a284-8d15ea6206eb:1 
       Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
   blob:http://localhost:3000/3274933a-1620-4b0a-b35f-1e226f37d8a8:1 
      Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
  blob:http://localhost:3000/eb49ff52-fd9e-4e94-a9bd-86e6e13e2b08:1 
    Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of the state object with updated data to rerender happens. Consider the `uid` to update a particular one.

Update `handleUploadPost` as below in `HeaderProfile.jsx`.

```
const handleUploadPost = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    multisavedAcc(prevState => {
        return prevState.map(item => {
            if (item.uid === "1123151") {
                return {
                    ...item,
                    gallery: [
                        ...item.gallery,
                        { img: "new_img", description: "text" }
                    ]
                };
            } else {
                return item
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks its working my problem now is just to pass it to Guest. Thank you again Mr.!

Comment: but if any possible..is there easiest path to do this? rather than that long line?

Comment: This is the correct way to update state using callback. Otherwise you won't get added items in the view

Comment: are you using a express server? you can use multer middleware => https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: no  thanks I got it already.

Comment: I have an issue when I'm refreshing the page the images vanishes but in the localStorage is still in there I believe there is some issue behind this. I came back here cause I got an issue about it.. Look at this code bro imma edit the post here.

Comment: Please reply sir I need one more solution for my issue..

Comment: what do you mean by localStorage? is it component state or browser's localStorage?

Comment: in the localStorage.json()...It is saved but when I refresh it the img doesn't show up. I'm thinking it is because of passing in the props.

Comment: when you refresh the page component will be remounted and state will be reintilized . It's the default behavior. If you want to save the images you need to store them in database connected to backend or using a cloud provider to store them

Comment: but why text doesn't ? I mean they can still show up in the return but image does not.

Comment: because the text is always in your initial state.

Comment: I actually can show it still in the return yesterday but when my code expand and I don't know if something affects by it. It is not showing anymore.

Comment: I mean like if still refresh it..It will still show but after I added some few codes..Its not showing anymore. I actually did it yesterday but i don't know if it is just a bug.

Comment: I think that's not the issue. I would try uploading the images to Cloudinary and load them when component remounts. here is a code sandbox as well https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#code_explorer_chunked_asset_upload_from_the_client_side